# How to get the trends in a particular given range using scripts in elastic search?

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have tried using the script query but the date coverstion was difficult can anyone help how get the data by day or hour or by month which provide data similar to the picture below. Thanks (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YoOQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'format' feature to get the date fields according to your choice. 
I've taken an example from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_keys_2

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "sales_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "1M",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can further mix and match the format pattern given in this link for your specific use case 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html#date-format-pattern

For your use case the 'format' field would be 'd MMM'. 
Your request would be something similar something like below:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "sales_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "1M",
                "format" : "d MMM" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are no scripts in the above query. The thing you are looking for doesn't need any script usage

Comment: It did work but there is another aggregate query associated with the same thanks